# spring load xml definition without external url

Tags: xml, spring, load, definition

In my application which is using Spring framework, at top of my environment.xml I have the usual

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
">
```

Now I am trying to get rid of the dependency on these external URLs in case they are down.
Is there a way to load these XML definitions from some spring or whatever java library. If yes, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring will load the schema definitions from local resources, as they are included in spring jars. In each jar you find a `/META-INF/spring.schemas` file that maps the URIs to classpath resources.

Quote from [Spring reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration-spring-schemas):

> The properties file called 'spring.schemas' contains a mapping of XML Schema locations (referred to along with the schema declaration in XML files that use the schema as part of the 'xsi:schemaLocation' attribute) to classpath resources. This file is needed to prevent Spring from absolutely having to use a default EntityResolver that requires Internet access to retrieve the schema file.